# Метод equals возвращает false, когда true

Tags: java, sql, сравнение

Привожу фрагмент кода:

```
if (resultSet.next()) {

    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));                    
    System.out.println("///");
    System.out.println("resultset = " +resultSet.getString(1));
    System.out.println("studbilet = " + studbilet);
    System.out.println("/ / / ");

    String res = resultSet.getString(1);

    if (res.equals(studbilet)) {
    /* Действия */
    } else {
        result = "Нет студента с таким номером студ. билета";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

На консоли:

```
///
resultset = БИ14007     
studbilet = БИ14007
/ / / 
Нет студента с таким номером студ. билета
```

Comment: Какой тип имеет поле, которое Вы получаете методом `resultSet.getString(1)`?

Comment: Думаю, и по названию понятно, что String.

Comment: Вы ведь с БД работаете?  `resultSet.getString(1)` возвращает Вам строку - это я знаю. Я же спрашиваю какой тип у поля в БД, которое Вы получаете этим методом?

Comment: Имя id, тип данных CHAR, тип данных БД bpchar, размер 12.

Comment: БД PostgreSQL///

Comment: попробуй сделать `System.out.println("resultset = " +resultSet.getString(1) + " str");`
`System.out.println("studbilet = " + studbilet + " str");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорей всего за счет типа `CHAR(12)` у вас значение `БИ14007` в базе данных дополняется до 12 символов. Получается Вы сравниваете:

```
studbilet = "БИ14007"
res = "БИ14007     "
```

Поэтому `if (res.equals(studbilet))` дает `false`.

Делайте `trim`:

```
String str = resultSet.getString(1);
String res = str.trim();

if (res.equals(studbilet)) {
/* Действия */
} else {
    result = "Нет студента с таким номером студ. билета";
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Или выберите другой тип для хранения `id` в БД.

Comment: Мб `.trim()` будет выглядеть красивей?..

Comment: @AGS17, да, конечно. Бес попутал, забыл про `trim()`. Исправил, спасибо)

Comment: А contains ?//1

Comment: @SadrutdinZaynukov `contains` тоже подойдет